# Как использовать какие-либо переменные в сообщениях телеграмм бота на python (pyTelegramBotAPI)?

Tags: python, telebot

Как использовать какие либо переменные в сообщениях телеграмм бота? хотел написать бота для игры в карты (для практики). Начал писать код, но столкнулся с  проблемой, текст после указания переменной пропадает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import telebot
import config
import random

from telebot import types

money = 1000
koloda = [6,7,8,9,10,2,3,4,11] * 4

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    sti = open('bob.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
    

    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton (text='нет ❌', callback_data='n')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton (text='да ', callback_data='y')

    markup_inline.add(item1, item2)


    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "На балансе ", money ,"\nГотов сыграть?", reply_markup=markup_inline)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True )
def otvet(call):

    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, 
        message_id=call.message.message_id, text='‌‌‍‍‎ответ засчитан',
        reply_markup=None)

    if call.data == 'n':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Ну и ладно')
    elif call.data == 'y':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тогда начнём!\nУ тебя')





bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тебе нужна конкатенация строк.

либо так:

```
"На балансе "+ str(money)+"\nГотов сыграть?",
```

либо ф-строкой вот так:

```
f'На балансе { money } \nГотов сыграть?'
```